# Variable for loaded file location Nginx

Tags: nginx

For this configuration

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html @proxy;
}
```

Is there an Nginx variable which refers to loaded file location? (I mean local path in the server)

Or is there a way to know which file is served?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`$request_filename`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_request_filename) yields the full path, regardless of HTTP response code or whether the file exists.

**Nginx config**

```
server {
  listen 127.0.0.1:888;
  root /tmp/nginx-root;
  index index.htm;
  add_header "x-request_filename" $request_filename always;
}
```

**Tests**

```
$ ls /tmp/nginx-root/
foo.htm  index.htm

$ curl -I 127.0.0.1:888/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-request_filename: /tmp/nginx-root/index.htm

$ curl -I 127.0.0.1:888/error
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
x-request_filename: /tmp/nginx-root/error
```